# Can't remove LibreOffice Writer from Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, uninstall, icons, libreoffice

I updated from LibreOffice 3.4 to 4.1.  Then I uninstalled 3.4.  The links to Libreoffice in the Launcher still worked, but I wanted to use the main LibreOffice icon instead of the individual app icons in the Launcher.  I was able to right click all of the icons and remove them from the Launcher except Writer.  It does not have the option to remove it.  Any ideas how I can remove it?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not at an Ubuntu machine right now, I will update this when I can get to one.

You should take a look in the d-conf editor, specifically in com/cananonical/Unity/launcher

Comment: `ls /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-*`

Comment: /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-base.desktop  /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop     /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop         /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop  /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop  /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop  /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop

Comment: ok - once I restarted, it was gone from the Launcher... weird.